# binary size of compiled git 4 times larger than installed one

Tags: makefile, compilation

I compiled git for my first time because centos stucks at 1.8.x.
I followed these instructions:

```
make configure ;# as yourself
./configure --prefix=/usr ;# as yourself
make all doc ;# as yourself
make install install-doc install-html;# as root
```

the compilation worked well, but looking at the binaries I noticed all of them a larger than the installed ones by rpm.
i.e. CentOS7 git binary is:

- by rpm (1.8.3.1) = 1,5MB
- self compiled (2.9.3) = 9,3MB

I looked around but didn't find a switch for compilation which reduces the size. Comparing the compiled binaries to "IUS Community Project" build (git 2.9.2.1 ~1,5MB), my compiled ones are also 4 times larger.

Thanks for a hint, making them smaller ;-)

Comment: Did you try stripping them?  Run `strip .../git` etc. to remove debug information.  Also, of course the newer version of Git will have more features and be somewhat larger.  And finally, you might just check the output of `ldd .../git` and see if there's a significant difference in the libraries listed; possibly something was statically linked in your build (this is highly unlikely).

Comment: wow fast answer - thanks!
strip was the solution, I wasn't aware that debug information is included by default. My windows compiler produces debug only set by flag.
Now it's 1,8 MB instead of 9,3

Answer (score 0):

The Solution by MadScientist:

strip was the solution, I wasn't aware that debug information is included by default. My windows compiler produces debug only set by flag.
Now it's 1,8 MB instead of 9,3